# How to install/connect Miniature Circuit Breakers ( MCB )

Tags: electrical, wiring, electrical-panel

What's the best way to connect the Miniature Circuit Breakers ?

Is it when the Line is coming downward or upwards ? I am confused as I have seen two different wiring's.

I want to know where I should connect an incoming and outgoing supply ?

Comment: A bit more information would be helpful. 
I was taught top to bottom, front to back and left to right , not only for phase marking but for power. Some bring power in from the bottom I have seen people get shocked including myself because most do go top to bottom. 
A photo of your setup would be helpful you do want to continue with the same method that is in use or you set up a hazard.

Comment: OK, "Miniature circuit breakers" is basically describing all modern circuit breakers everywhere, from FPE to Homeline to Pushmatic to Bosch ones for cars.  You really need to narrow it down "a little" for us... e.g. link the product.

Comment: MCB is the term  most commonly used in IEC countries to describe DIN rail mounted Mini-Circuit Breakers. and they can be either Wire-In / Wire-Out or you can add a "comb" style bus bar to gang them together. The combs will actually fit on either end of a row of breakers, hence it being possible to back-feed an entire lineup of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MCB can be MOUNTED in either direction, but the wiring LINE IN side is always the end toward which the handle points when the breaker is ON.

That doesn't mean people do it correctly every time, and it will technically function if wired the other way (referred to as "back feeding"), but there are potential safety issues with back feeding.

Comment: I do agree they are usually DIN but not all are.

Comment: Is backfeeding really an issue with unit mounted circuit breakers?  (My understanding is that unless it's marked for polarity or LINE/LOAD, it's freely backfeedable; it'd be odd to see a MCB standard that wasn't that way, since it'd conflict with UL 489 as a result)